# How to click on the element with text as Logout as per the HTML through SeleniumWebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

on mobile version of the site I need to click on the category Logout, but xpath doesn't work (xpath clicked at first category at list), tried to use this example

```
WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'link logout hidden-md-up icon-logout')]"));
logout.click();
```

but it doesn't work anyway. Maybe someone know how to solve this?

Screen with code example (highlighted the category I'm trying to click on)
[image]

Comment: Please repost your HTML as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In your example, your xpath is pointing to the `<ul>` and I'm guessing clicking on that is the same as clicking on the first `<li>` under it.
2. You can also try referencing the text.

   `WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'logout') and text()[contains(.,'Logout')]]"`

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Logout** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='account-action-list']//li[@class='link logout hidden-md-up icon-logout']/span"))).click();
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it also click at first category in list, but I need the last one category

Comment: @Daria Update the question with text based relevant HTML for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

try using this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'logout')]//span")).click();
```

Comment: No, and I think the problem is not in the locators, because all the proposed locators are correct and will be run in another case. But not on this list. I decided to logout by clearing the cache, because clicking on the category does not work yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'Logout')"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with link text method or partial link text method.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Logout")).click();
```

**Ensure the parameter text matches the text in the DOM**

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I think the problem is not in the locators, because all the proposed locators are correct and will be run in another case. But not on this list. I decided to logout by clearing the cache, because clicking on the category does not work yet

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems with your locator:

1. As was pointed out: Your locator is `ul[contains(@class, '...')]`, however those clasess are on the `li` element. So your element cannot be found.
2. In HTML, the `class` attribute is a space-separated **list** of classes, and the order in that list in not guaranteed. You can use WebDriver's `By.className()` to target any **one** of those classes; for example `driver.findElement(By.className("logout"))`.

Even these might still not solve your problem. You may need to target the `span` node under the `li`.

Update:

A selector like `By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'link')` is almost certainly not going to work, as there are probably multiple elements in your page with the class `link`. In that case Selenium will pick the first one, which most likely is not the one you want.

In order for us to help you get the specific selector, you would have to provide more of your HTML.

Comment: 1. I edit the locator, but it still click at first category in list

`WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'link')]"));
logout.click();`

Comment: and second example also click at first category in list
`driver.findElement(By.className("logout"))`

Comment: @Daria I updated my answer with additional information.